Is there a way to implicitly deserialize based on @type property, without annotating children on each parent class without use of reflection?
I have the following structure and I am trying to avoid all the type info and sub type annotations on parent since concrete expressions (e.g AnotherExpression) could be managed and extended by different teams on separate modules. Reflection most probably needs to be avoided.
public interface Expression<T> {
 ....
}

public interface BooleanExpression extends Expression<Boolean> {
 ....
}


public class AnotherExpression implements BooleanExpression {

  private final boolean value;


}

public class Wrapper {
   public Expression expression;
}


I want to be able to deserialize the following json string:
      String json =
      """
      { "expression": {
        "@type": "AnotherExpression",
        "value": true
      }} 
      """;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Wrapper exp = mapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class);


but I am getting
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'AnotherExpression' as a subtype of [...].Expression  known type ids = [] (for POJO property 'constant')
I have found approaches like using objectMapper.registerSubtypes https://www.baeldung.com/java-jackson-polymorphic-deserialization
that also needs reflection..
I even tried annotation @JsonTypeInfo and subtypes on Expression but still nothing works

why you want to skip explicitly deserialize based on @type and Reflection, do u just want to outside the config(@JsonTypeInfo +@JsonSubTypes ) from interface(Expression ) , if this is your purpose , u can use mixin to separate the interface and its annotaion config

I want external people to add more type deserializations on their extensions of my library.. so I can't know all the children implementations to be put in the parent.. I believe this can be done with Java Modules that can be registered during compile time and do register subtypes afterwards - I have seen it in a library doing exactly that. I will come up with a solution that works without Mixins I guess

whether use @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY) match you case,  then this config value propagates to all subtypes if u don't need a logical name for subtype

So based on the approach of library Jackson Databind JavaTimeModule what worked for us is to create a new module like that for each of the teams - it seems @JavaTypeName is irrelevant:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.NamedType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

class MyTeamModule extends SimpleModule {
    public MyTeamModule() {
        super("MyTeamModule");
        this.registerSubtypes(
            new NamedType(AnotherExpression.class, "AnotherExpression"),
            ....
        )

}

Then what is needed for the ObjectMapper is to call findAndRegistermodules()
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();

We may need to add @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, property = "@type") on each of the interfaces but I am not sure if they are actually needed.. unless we want a different property other than @type
With this approach another team can create a module that will be registered on the ObjectMapper and we don't need to have all the annotations on the parent class since we don't know what each team will provide in their modules, and how they will want to extend the core functionality. Their code might be in different modules/packages etc and the core functionality can be in a jar without the need to redeploy/recompile the whole project.
